# Add print servers to printmanagement.msc

Tags: c#, .net

I have a small windows form with a text box.  A user types the hostname into the textbox then clicks a button that launches printmanagement.msc.  The user then has to go through the manual steps of retyping that hostname into the Add/Remove servers dialog before they can administer the print server on the remote machine.

The goal is that I'd like to launch the printmanagement.msc snap-in then automatically add the selected hostname to the print server list.

I'm currently doing it with a hand-built macro, which is frankly kinda sloppy =(.

I haven't been able to find any useful command line options for printmanagement.msc but I'm hoping someone has heard of a library I can tap into for it.  Or better yet, command line arguments that'll do what I'm looking for.

I'm using c# with .net for the bulk of my form.  The macro is currently using auto-it but I'd like to get rid of it entirely.

Any help will be appreciated!  =)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use GPOs for this?  My understanding is that this is the preferred method for mass deployment on a domain, which if you do this often enough to program a solution, sounds like the case @user2510724

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  Didn't realize I had a comment on this thread.  

My environment does use GPO's for printer pushes, however, we have many satellite offices with less than ideal bandwidth.  If we're doing mass system refreshes this leads to offices coming to a stand-still until all machines have pulled the necessary drivers over the connection which could mean an extra couple of hours while we stand around waiting for the group policy to finish up.

We have been mapping printers manually on the machines before going to site to alleviate this.

Comment: This sounds like a toughie...you could use autoit to maximize the window and use mouse clicks (after disabling user input) instead of your keystroke method to do this, which might work...otherwise, what you might want to do is push the drivers from the CO to a single machine at each SO, and have the rest of the boxes pull from their SO's LAN machine instead of the CO...but I'm pretty much out of ideas.